# Transferring Workbook code to Module corrupts UsedRange.Rows variable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm moving my code to buttons so the user can use them without requiring to go into the Dev tab and manually running code snippets.

One of the snippets allows the user split the file based on what x column say (meaning for each value a new file it's created), that  code is stored directly in the workbook code. What I'm faced with when moving the code to a module (to run on buttons) displays an error on `UsedRange.Rows` variable which copies the content of that cell into that new file. I've tried creating a worksheet variable but that stills displays that `UsedRange.Rows` variable it's not defined.

```
Option Explicit
'CORTA LOS DATOS EN BASE AL RESPOSABLE ASIGNADO
Sub splitRespVP()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim p As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    '''''''''''
    Dim key As Variant
    Dim d As Object, i As Long, lr As Long
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lr
      d.Item(Range("T" & i).Value) = 1
    Next i
    '''''''''''
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each key In d.Keys()
        Workbooks.Add
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        ThisWorkbook.Activate

        WritePersonToWorkbook wb, key 'd.Item

        wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\sdoRespVP_" & key
        wb.Close
    Next key
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set wb = Nothing
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    MsgBox "Terminé."
    
End Sub

'ESCRIBE LOS DATOS PERTENECIENTE A ALGUN RESPONSABLE DEL DICCIONARIO
Sub WritePersonToWorkbook(ByVal respWB As Workbook, _
                          ByVal Person As String)
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim personRows As Range     '
    Dim firstRW As Range        '
    For Each rw In UsedRange.Rows 'HERE IS THE ERROR!
        If Not Not firstRW Is Nothing And Not IsNull(rw) Then
            Set firstRW = rw  '
        End If
        If Person = rw.Cells(1, 20) Then
            If personRows Is Nothing Then
                Set personRows = firstRW
                Set personRows = Union(personRows, rw)
            Else
                Set personRows = Union(personRows, rw)
            End If
        End If
    Next rw

    personRows.Copy respWB.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
    Set personRows = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: `UsedRange` is a property of a Worksheet object. You haven't qualified it to a worksheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify what worksheet you want the UsedRows of. For example, if you wanted to use the whatever worksheet the user currently has selected, you could do this:

```
'ESCRIBE LOS DATOS PERTENECIENTE A ALGUN RESPONSABLE DEL DICCIONARIO
Sub WritePersonToWorkbook(ByVal respWB As Workbook, _
                          ByVal Person As String)
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim personRows As Range     '
    Dim firstRW As Range        '

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'Get whatever worksheet the user happens to have selected

    For Each rw In ws.UsedRange.Rows 'HERE IS THE ERROR!
        If Not Not firstRW Is Nothing And Not IsNull(rw) Then
            Set firstRW = rw  '
        End If
        If Person = rw.Cells(1, 20) Then
            If personRows Is Nothing Then
                Set personRows = firstRW
                Set personRows = Union(personRows, rw)
            Else
                Set personRows = Union(personRows, rw)
            End If
        End If
    Next rw
    personRows.Copy respWB.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
    Set personRows = Nothing
End Sub
```

Note that you should actually specify the workbook and name of the sheet you want; ActiveSheet is just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: How can I specify the worksheet explicitly from a external workbook? Using ActiveSheet makes the code break on the second iteration.

Comment: Well, how how were you specifying it before? You need some way to identify what data you want to copy, but I can't tell you what that is with the information you've provided. Do you know the workbook and worksheet name? If so, use those.

Comment: I was using it directly on the ThisWorkbook object, but I moved the code to a module.

Comment: Uhh, ok... But surely you don't want to just pick a random worksheet to copy from, right? Is the user specifying what worksheet they want? Is it always the same worksheet? Is there only ever going to be one worksheet in the workbook?

Comment: Yep, the user pastes data in the workbook (first sheet where the "template" is), goes to the second worksheet (where buttons are stored) and runs the code.

Comment: Yes to which one? Does the template have a set name or not?

Comment: It's always the same worksheet, as I said, the user fills this template and runs the code.

Comment: If you know the name of the worksheet, and it's in the same workbook as your code, do `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName")`. If the name may change, but it's always the first worksheet, do `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)`.